# build list of lists using comprehension lists two at a time

Tags: python

I am using the following code to build a list of lists:

```
res = []
for i in I:
   res.append(x)
   res.append(y[i])
```

so my final list is `[x, y[0], x, y[1],...]` where `x` and `y[i]` are also lists.

Is there a way building this list using list comprehensions, instead of for loop?

Comment: You want the entire list `x` duplicated at each even index of `res`?

Comment: yes, I would like to duplicate x at each even index of res.

Comment: What is `I`? Please tell me it isn't `range(len(y))`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ... think ... this might be close to what you want:

```
res = [z for z in ((x, y[i]) for i in I)]
```

Comment: that should be [z for z in ((x, y[i]) for i in I)]

Comment: Alternatively, `[z for i in I for z in (x, y[i])]`.

Comment: Wouldn't that result in a list of tuples not a flat list of values as the questioner asks?

Comment: @Ross: No, multiple `for` clauses lead to nested loops (with the first `for` being the outer loop).

Comment: @Ross he didn't ask for a flat list of value (unless the question changed).  He asked for a list of lists.

Comment: the original one is a list of tuples, the F.J. one is the correct list

Comment: the answer provided by F.J is the one I am looking for, how should I proceed in terms of accepting an answer?

Answer (score 2):

[Itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) can help with this sort of thing:

```
>>> y = I = range(5)
>>> x = 'x'
>>> res = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((x, y[i]) for i in I))
>>> res
['x', 0, 'x', 1, 'x', 2, 'x', 3, 'x', 4]
```

Comment: list(chain.from_iterable(izip(repeat(x), y)))

Answer (score 2):

```
res = reduce(tuple.__add__,  [(x, y[i]) for i in I])
```

Comment: This produces a tuple, not a list, and has pretty horrible complexity (repeatedly create intermediate tuples just to copy the items for creation of yet another intermediate tuple, and so on).

Comment: note: reduce is in functools in python3, and this produces a tuple

Comment: yup, that's right. Does that make sense to put the same item in a list every second position anyway?

Answer (score 2):

The map style:

```
res = []
map(res.extend, ((x, y[i]) for i in I))
```

The reduce style:

```
res = reduce(lambda arr, i: arr + [x, y[i]], I, [])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sum(([x, y[i]] for i in I), [])
```

Like bpgergo's, but with lists, and with a simpler way of joining them together.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do what you are looking for:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, izip, repeat
>>> x = [1, 2]
>>> y = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
>>> list(chain(*izip(repeat(x), y)))
[[1, 2], ['a', 'b'], [1, 2], ['c', 'd']]
```

Note that this will have shallow copies of the inner lists (same as other solutions), so make sure you understand the following behavior:

```
>>> z = list(chain(*izip(repeat(x), y)))
>>> z
[[1, 2], ['a', 'b'], [1, 2], ['c', 'd']]
>>> x.append(3)
>>> z
[[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b'], [1, 2, 3], ['c', 'd']]
>>> z[0].append(4)
>>> z
[[1, 2, 3, 4], ['a', 'b'], [1, 2, 3, 4], ['c', 'd']]
>>> y[1].append('e')
>>> z
[[1, 2, 3, 4], ['a', 'b'], [1, 2, 3, 4], ['c', 'd', 'e']]
```